# Formatting of scientific numbers

Tags: php, printf, scientific-notation

Trying to print out a scientific number, I have tried different kinds of PHP number formats, including sprintf, etc.

```
<?php
$layer1capacityratio = 3.9008133852857E-5;
echo sprintf('%f',$layer1capacityratio);
```

This outputs "0.000039" but I would like to output "0.003901%".

I am not sure what I have missed. If someone can point me in the right direction I would be grateful!

Comment: Please note the edits I made to your question. You should only include the minimum relevant information needed to reproduce the problem. The fact that you're getting this number from a JSON data source via HTTP does not have any bearing to the question. This also applies to question tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to display a number as a percent, you multiply it by 100 and add a percent sign.

```
<?php
$layer1capacityratio = 3.9008133852857E-5;
echo sprintf('%f%%',$layer1capacityratio * 100);
```

You can also use [the format string](https://www.php.net/sprintf) to control significant figures in the output:

```
echo sprintf('%.8f%%',$layer1capacityratio * 100);
```